# JAXB External Binding File Error

Tags: java, binding, jaxb, external

so I have written an external binding file for waterml2.xsd and so far have fixed the [Error] Property "Rows" is already defined and [Error] Property "Title" is already defined.

After fixing those I now am getting multiple issues dealing with collisions. For example:

> [ERROR] A class/interface with the same name
>   "net.opengis.gml._3.SecondDefiningParameter" is already in use. Use a
>   class customization to resolve this conflict.
>
> [Error] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.

---

This is what the binding file looks like:

```
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0">
<!-- In geometryPrimitives.xsd, fix so element and attribute both with name "rows" don't conflict -->
<bindings schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/geometryPrimitives.xsd" version="3.2.1.2">
<bindings node="//xs:group/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='rows']">
<property name="rowsElement"/>
</bindings>
</bindings>
<!-- In xlink.xsd, fix so element and attributes don't have the same "titles" conflict -->
<bindings schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
<schemaBindings>
<package name="net.opengis.wfs._2_1"/>
</schemaBindings>
</bindings>
<bindings schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
<bindings node="//xs:attributeGroup[@name='locatorAttrs']">
<bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@ref='xlink:title']">
<property name="LocatorAttrsTitle"/>
</bindings>
</bindings>
<bindings node="//xs:group[@name='locatorModel']">
<bindings node=".//xs:element[@ref='xlink:title']">
<property name="LocatorModelTitle"/>
</bindings>
</bindings>
<bindings node="//xs:attributeGroup[@name='arcAttrs']">
<bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@ref='xlink:title']">
<property name="ArcAttrsTitle"/>
</bindings>
</bindings>
<bindings node="//xs:group[@name='arcModel']">
<bindings node=".//xs:element[@ref='xlink:title']">
<property name="ArcModelTitle"/>
</bindings>
</bindings>
</bindings>
</bindings>
```

---

If anyone has any suggestions or has dealt with the WaterML 2.0 Schema before I would appreciate some help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The OGC schemas need a little additional binding information to correctly run through JAXB. You are a lot better off relying on the hard work at https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas.

To use the highsource bindings, it’s probably best to just clone the repository and use maven to build the bindings (there is good maven build support in this project). I.e.

```
git clone https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas.git
mvn install –D skipTests
```

I skipped the tests to speed things up and I had an issue with one test failing.

You could also just import the base pom.xml into Eclipse (or whatever IDE you use) and let the maven build go through.

Once it builds, you should end up with your bindings under the relevant folder. E.g. WaterML2.0:

```
ls waterml/2.0/target/generated-sources/xjc/net/opengis/waterml/v_2_0/

CategoricalTVPType.java
CategoricalTimeseriesType.java
CollectionPropertyType.java
CollectionType.java
CommentBlockPropertyType.java
and so on..
```

And there’s a XJB file in the target/classes folder.